# How can I expose a subset of my SQL Azure database to customers for reporting?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, azure-acs

I'm trying to determine whether Azure SQL Reporting can be used to provide reporting on an application we're hosting in Azure with an Azure SQL database back-end.

Ideally we'd like to be able to offer users the ability to create their own reports. To do this, we need to expose to them the subset of the data which applies to the organisation they're associated with.

Users identities come from federated providers via Azure ACS.

What can I do to customise the data exposed and offer only the subset a user is allowed to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something you can implement in Reporting Services.

I have had similar situations using standard Windows users and we created views on the tables that joined to some mapping table (e.g. company and user) and used SUSER_SNAME() to return the current user login name. Users only had permissions to access the data via the views and their login name acted as a filter on the rows.